# JS data analytics library for tsv/csv data

Tags: javascript, csv

Data I am working on is stored in number of files ranging from 1 to 60-50 MB.
I am interested in showing this data in tabular form and running some basic aggregate statistics like one would do with SQL or R.

I could naturally do this with SQL on the backend, but I am interested to know if there is
any kind of JavaScript library that would let me do selects, averages, counts, etc. from the browser (or from the Node server) where I do not need to have the full database backend.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found answer to my own question.
I am posting here as some others might find it useful.

I am looking to use the [Miso library](http://misoproject.com).
Take a look at the [API](http://misoproject.com/dataset/api.html). It looks quite useful. 
Here is another blog [post](http://tbranyen.com/post/thoughts-on-development-using-couchdb-with-nodejs) that shows how to use it with Node and CouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can have a look at this : https://github.com/aaronsnoswell/csvjson.js

Then to display it, the easiest way I know is the "ng-repeat" from angularJS : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

And for the statistics part : http://www.jstat.org/

Answer (score 0):

For data processing you can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library. It implements all important SQL functionality plus you can write your own functions. Also it can import TSV data directly to SELECT statement. Alasql can work together with [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) or other visualization toolkits.

This is an example of data processing from TSV data file with SQL's SELECT and user-defined function:

```
alasql.fn.myFunc = function(z) {
    return z*z*z;
}
var res = alasql('SELECT SUM(x), AVG(y) FROM TSV("mydata.tsv",{headers:true}) \
    WHERE myFunc(z) > 1000');
```

Due your files are to large, it is better to use Node.js rather than browser.